# Can't edit block in Drupal

Tags: drupal

I have recently started using Drupal but I am having a bit of difficulty editing some blocks. I've gone into the blocks admin menu and I can see a list of all of the different blocks being used and they have the configure option next to them.

If I click configure on some of them, on the next page I am given the 'edit block' box but on others the box doesn't show up (e.g. footer). How can I make the edit box show up or is there another way to edit them?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some modules, like the menu module, add blocks with auto-generated content that cannot be edited directly from the blocks admin page. Usually only content blocks added by yourself will have the edit block content option.

Footer will be a menu block, so there will be no editable area. If you want to make changes to the menu you'd need to edit the menu rather than the block.

Comment: Thanks monkeyninja, I didn't realise they were uneditable purposely. I found the secton where to edit it in the end..it had an image menu added into the block which someone had added in so I went into image menus instead and can now edit it

Answer (score 3):

1] visit this link http://drupal.org/project/block_edit and download module and install it on your site.

2] visit this link to apply setting `admin/settings/block_edit`.

What actually this module do?

It's provide a edit link on block itself where you are viewing it. Now clicking on edit link will redirect you to specific block edit  page. This means need not to go deep inside and find block you want to edit.